# I'm seeing performance problems with postfix accepting mail when the queue is already large, any suggestions?

Tags: postfix, performance-tuning

I use postfix to do final delivery for a mail system I've written. So this postfix installation only accepts mail from me, and bounces. When the postfix queue is empty, it can accept a piece of mail in 5ms or so. When the queue has 150k-200k messages or so, the handoff speed from me to postfix is really slow, like 50-100 sometimes 500ms.

I have log times on every piece of the SMTP conversation, so I can see where the time is going. Some of it is when I'm waiting for a response from the RCPT TO command, but the vast majority of the time disappears after I send the final dot, before I get the "250 okay queued as..." response.

I'm thinking maybe the RCPT TO delay is in a DNS lookup, but that doesn't help me with the queuing time.
I keep one TCP socket open for all the email I'm sending, and I RSET the conversation for each mail, so there's no time lost to making and breaking TCP connections, it's all waiting for postfix to queue the message.

Everything I've read about performance tuning postfix has to do with queue management and sending mail for this and that domain here and there. But I'm concerned with getting postfix just to accept the mail quickly in the first place.

Is there any way to find out what postfix is doing with all this time or is there a way to make it go faster? The /var/spool/postfix queue is on local disk, so I can't make that any faster.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please paste some configs of postfix and logs it will help to find solution

Comment: STOP SPAMMING. 150k-200k is not a usual mail volume unless you are an ISP. And they have multiple outgoing servers to cope with that.

Comment: @mailq - it's not an unusual mail volume for a school, for example: the university I went to had routine mail queues in that range and only a pair of mail servers (5k students + 1.5k facstaff)

Comment: Which means even in worst case only 6.5k mails at a time.

Comment: I'm not spamming, but I appreciate your concern. If you want to stop spamming, you're talking to the wrong guy, you want to be designing a better mail system that isn't as inherently designed NOT to prohibit spam as SMTP.

Comment: @mailq (or anyone else reading more recently): go through the first ten legitimate items in your mail folder, and consider the likely scale of the services handling those emails.  Just because you only deal with small scale systems doesn't mean those are the only legitimate ones.

Comment: I have found over the years people tend to think in terms of their situation and have a hard time imagining anybody else's life being any different. Such is being human.

Answer (score 6):

Set the following in `main.cf`

```
hash_queue_depth = 3
hash_queue_names = deferred, defer, incoming, active
```

This produces subdirectories in the incoming and active queues so that the flat directories don't contain all mails at once. They are now put into subdirectories.

But note: Having 150k-200k messages waiting for delivery shows an incredible wrong understanding of a balanced sending of mails. This looks like spamming to me...

Comment: Looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, but every once in a while, it's not a duck.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions was to have a secondary mail server that handles all the bounces that are waiting to be delivered, this was the best solutios to keep the real email going through.

Comment: bounces aren't a big part of the equation and the machine has tons of capacity so I can't imagine that the few bounces we get are really slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but the technology has not changed much / the existing answers are not very helpful.

> When the queue has 150k-200k messages or so, the handoff speed from me to postfix is really slow

By the way this question is presented, it would appear that the OP is referring the *active* queue here (Postfix has multiple queues). And Postfix is doing exactly what it should do to prevent itself from choking. The active queue is where all the clever stuff with delivery scheduling. When it gets too large, scheduling becomes the bottleneck.

When you see load related performance problems, it's a good idea to check to load, cpu and io metrics to see if there is a hardware bottleneck.

Where you are operating a send only relay, reducing the in_flow_delay here will reduce throttling of clients. But you need to keep the size of the active queue down. Limiting the rate at which messages are passed from the incoming queue to the active queue can help here. But the best solution is to get stuff out of the active queue faster. The best thing you can do here is good reputation management, fast DNS, and, if possible, distributing the sending over multiple IP addresses. Reducing the retry frequency will also help with rate at which the active queue fills, and with providers whom limit acceptance based on the frequency of connection attempts.

SPF, DMARC and DKIM (correctly configured) should be considered as essential.

Because everyone invents there own mechanisms for dealing with spam there will always be outliers - for which you'll need to setup custom transports.